# Handle default web page with little information for search?

Tags: search, seo, meta

Would like to garner opinions. We've created a website for a gay members club and they wanted the default landing page to mysterious with little information on it.

As such the Default.aspx only contains a form asking for some personal details. Users can click a button to skip this content and go to an AboutUs page.

The problem is, because we cannot control what information Google uses for the site description in search results, it is picking up the forms fields - which obviously do not makes sense as a description.

I think there are two options to counter this:

- Use Robots.txt to block access to Default.aspx and only allow access to AboutUs.aspx
- Write a description and title in a H1 tag but make the text colour the same as the background colour

Could I get opinions which method people will think is best for search results?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would not block or try and deceive Google.

Make sure the title tag for the page is good and descriptive. Around 70 characters to explain what the website is about.

Same goes for your meta description. About two sentences to continue on from the title information.

Comment: Not sure you're grasping the point Tiggerito, not that I'm not appreciative of your reply. Using Robots.txt is a valid way to block access to your content for crawlers, I've just never used it on the landing page before. The description is good, but you cannot force Google to use it. As such, because the form is longer (I imagine) it is picking up the form.

Comment: If you block that page from Google then Google will not send people to the page. Therefore search visitors will enter via the about us page. Would this defeat what you're trying to do as they will bypass your landing page? Most backlinks would be to the domain so people finding you that way will still see the landing page. You may also cause ranking issues as you will be blocking the page that people link to and provide you with PageRank.

Comment: That's the crux of my question. In the end Google starting picking up the description so there was no need to block access to the front page. Thanks for your help either way.